# How to order a multicolumn Hashmap<String><String> on android?

Tags: java, android, hashmap

Anyone know how to order a hashmap by an specific column "distance"?

```
double distanceInMeters = location.distanceTo(location2);
DecimalFormat doubleform = new DecimalFormat("0.0");

HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id_ret")));
map.put("nome", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nome")));
map.put("endereco", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("endereco")));
map.put("bairro", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("bairro")));
map.put("cidade", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cidade")));
map.put("uf", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("uf")));
map.put("distance", doubleform.format(distanceInMeters/1000)); <= Need to order this column!
list.add(map);
```

Thanks!

Comment: don't use an HashMap if the order matters

Comment: Ok. But, what I must use for multcolumns listview?

Comment: If you want an ordered Map, you should use a Map that is-a SortedMap, for example, TreeMap. That said, could you be more specific about your ordering scheme. What does ordering by distance means? A TreeMap would order elements according to the order of the Keys you put into the map. So if your key is a String and put id, name, distance etc as several possible String keys, that will not order the elements as per distance. So could you please post a more detailed problem description?

Comment: This hashmap contains a list of addresses with the calculated distance between the address shown and a specific location. I have to show to the user the list ordered by shortest distance.

Comment: And what are id, nome, endereco, bairro, cidade, uf etc? Are they specifics about a certain route? How about you have a Route class that has-a those details. You can then have a TreeMap with distance as the key and Route objects as values. You could have getters for all those specifics about a Route in the Route class. You wouldn't need a List then. By having distance as the key I mean, the actual value of the distance as the key.

Comment: Are specific fields of a record, representing the vendor id, name , address , neighborhood , city, state and the distance that must be ordered from smallest to largest.

Comment: Can you provide me an example of this TreeMap with "Route" class ordered, please?

Comment: So I am guessing what you currently have is this. You have a location say A. And your each HashMap contains id, name address neighbourhood, city state and distance of A from another location say B. Similarly you have another HashMap that contains these values for another route say A to C. And you have a list of such HashMaps. is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I calculate the distance when I fill the hashmap and use this hashmap in a list.

Answer (score 0):

By Route class, I mean something as follows.

```
public class Route implements Comparable<Route> {

    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String distance; 
    // add other fields that you require

    //constructor and/or static methods


    public String getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    // other getters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Route o) {
        // Teach your compareTo method to compare routes by distance. 
        // Might involve comparing the double types.
    }
    // Add equals and hashCode methods too that are consistent with the
    // compareTo method. Add toString method also.



}
```

And then I would read those column values and create my Route objects and put them in a List as follows.

```
List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<>();
routes.add(new Route(.....));
Collections.sort(routes);// this will sort the routes.
```

We are using a List cause you can have Routes with same distance multiple times.

Comment: Just a little disclaimer - it's important - : Actually I just noticed that you've tagged Android in there also. My response is with respect to Java programming only. If Android APIs have better options, I don't know about them.